# How to getting rows from Laravel's belongsToMany relations?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've problem with belongsToMany relation on Laravel.Firstly, I want to describe my table structe.There 3 different table has got on my database.Projects, Skills and ProjectSkills are my tables.There is a structure of my model.It's working perfectly when I tried to insert project with skills.However, it's not listing skills when I tried to get a single project.

**ProjectController:**

```
$Project = Projects::with('skills')->where('Projects.SefTitle','=',$ProjectSef)->first();
return View::make('Projects.view',array('Project'=>$Project));
```

**Project(Model)**

```
...
public function skills(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Skills','ProjectSkills','ProjectID','SkillID');
}
...
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($Project->Skills as $Skill)
    {{$Skill->Title}} <br />
@endforeach
```

**Database and Datasets:**

[image: ProjectSkills]

[image: Skills]

[image: Projects]

Comment: What's the return value of `Projects::with('skills')->where('Projects.SefTitle','=',$ProjectSef)->take(1)->toSql();`? And does it work as expected if you run it in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: The output of toSql() is `select * from Projects where Projects.SefTitle = ? limit 1`.Actually, it's just getting a single project on mysql.My problem is about Skills.

Comment: Puh now I'm running short of ideas...
I suppose you have set all the primary keys on your models? like `protected $primaryKey = 'ProjectID'`

Comment: Yeah I've double checked it again many of them has got a primaryKey var. on model.However, There aren't any primarykey column on my ProjectSkills table.

Comment: The primary key on the pivot table shouldn't make a difference. In fact, I believe you wouldn't even need one... You said you were able to insert data including skills? did you use the relationship?

Comment: Yep. I've used the synch() function for the inserting data.It inserted to db by the replationship.

Comment: Alright, that means the relationship *should* be fine... Another `toSql` test: `$Project->skills()->toSql()`

Comment: I think there might be problem on that side.
`select * from Skills inner join ProjectSkills on Skills.SkillID = ProjectSkills.SkillID where ProjectSkills.ProjectID is null`

Comment: Yes that `null` in there is definitely wrong. But I have no idea where it is coming from. Could you try getting the project directly by ID? `Project::with('skills')->find(57)`

Comment: The output is: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Projects.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from Projects where Projects.id = 57 limit 1)`

Comment: This looks like you're missing the `$primaryKey` variable in the `Projects` class, since it's trying to use `id` the default name for PKs

Comment: Yeah its fixed.Can you please remove your last comment and insert it as a reply because if some people might have a same problem in the future.

Comment: Hurray :) Writing an answer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For primary keys that differ from the default Laravel uses (which is just `id`) make sure you define your primary key on every of your model classes:

```
class Projects extends Eloquent {
    protected $primaryKey = 'ProjectID';
}
```